# SEO crawler DDOSing sites

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, caching, ddos

I have a customer that runs 36 websites (many thousands of pages) on a round robin with sticky affinity load-balanced set of IIS servers - the infra is entirely AWS based (r3.2xl - 8 VCPU, 60.5 GiB RAM)

To get straight to the point, the site is configured to 'cache on access' using standard in-memory caching with ASP.NET 4.6 and static assets through Cloudfront.  The site on a 'cold start' makes both SQL Server queries for content, and separate elasticsearch queries at runtime to determine hreflang alternate language tags - this basically queries which versions of the URL are available in different languages for SEO reasons.  This query has been optimised to be a lookup on a single index from a cross-index wildcard query.  As mentioned, the entire result is cached for 24h once all this has executed.

Under normal use conditions the site works perfectly.  As there are 36 sites running on a single box, the private set space gets allocated up to the max (99%) of physical RAM over time, as more and more content gets cached in memory.  I can end up with App Pools in excess of 1.5GiB which isn't ideal.  After this point, presumably the .NET LRU cache eviction algorithm is working overtime.

The problem I have, after some post-mortem review of the IIS logd, the customer is using an SEO bot tool, SEMrush, which essentially triggers a denial of service attack against the sites (thundering herd?) because of simultaneous requests for the 'long tail' of pages which are never viewed by a user and hence aren't stored in the cache.

The net result is a server brought to its knees, App Pool CPU usage all over the place, and an Elasticsearch queue length > 1000, huge ES heap growth, rejection rate - and eventually a crash.

The solutions I've thought about but haven't implemented:

1. Cloudfront all the sites - use a warm up script (although I don't think this will actually help as it's a cold start problem when all the pages expire, unless I could have a MOST recently used cache invalidation mechanism which invalidated pages on number of requests - say > 100, and left everything else persistent)
2. AWS Shield/WAF to provide some sort of rate limiting
3. Remove the runtime ES lookup all together and move to an eventually-consistent model which computes the hreflang lookup table elsewhere on a separate process.  Hpwever, the ES instances, whilst on a v1.3.1 version which is old, is a 3-node cluster which has a lot of CPU power and each node set to a 16GiB min/max heap so should be able to take that level of throughput?

Or all 3!

Has anyone come across this problem before and what was your solution? it must be fairly common especially for large sites which are hammered by SEO / DQM web crawlers?